# HTML-Loader is not working with Webpack 4 (appropriate loader)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm just trying to load an HTML file so I can use it as a component in react.
I've tried all sorts of configurations in webpack.config.js,  I've tried reinstalling html-loader, and I've looked at every tutorial/bug post I could find with no luck solving my issue.

***webpack.config.js***

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
        use: {
        loader: 'html-loader',
        options: {
        attrs: [':data-src']
            }
    }
},
```

***package.json***

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
  "classnames": "^2.2.6",
  "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
  "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
  "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
  "webpack": "^4.19.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
},
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "@babel/env",
    "@babel/react"
  ]
}
```

***index.jsx***

```
import test from './test.html'
```

***Error***

```
./src/test.html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
```

Comment: has anybody found solution to this yet? I'm having the same problem when importing html into js.

Answer (score 1):

you webpack.config.js must be like this

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: [path.resolve(__dirname, './index.js')],

    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    options: {
                        attrs: [':data-src']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/react']


                    }
                },
                resolve: { extensions: [".js", ".jsx"] }

            }

        ]
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "wb",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "test",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "build": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development "
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "MIT",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
        "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
        "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "webpack": "^4.19.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "react": "^16.6.3",
      "react-dom": "^16.6.3"
    }

  }
```

**tm.html**

```
<h1>hi test </h1>
<p>test test</p>
```

**index.js**

```
import tm  from './tm.html'

document.write(tm)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>test</title>        
</head>
<body>
    <script src="dist/app.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this for my config.js but still got the same error.  I did have the babel loader already in my original config as well.